# After upgrading from Cocoapods 0.39 to 1.1.1, getting error saying FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h file not found in GeoFire.m

Tags: firebase, geofire, cocoapods-1.1.1

I recently upgraded my Cocoapods from version 0.39 to 1.1.1. I am using both Firebase and GeoFire in my project. The project would build and compile perfectly fine before the upgrade. After the upgrade, I get an error that says:

'FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h file not found'

This error is located in the GeoFire.m file.

I've tried cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, restarting my computer, but nothing is working. I don't understand how all of the sudden GeoFire can't find the FirebaseDatabase header file, even though it never moved.  Has anyone seen this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured out a solution to the same issue. Try replacing the FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h with the path of the FirebaseDatabase.h in your project.

In Xcode, in the Navigator, unwind the directories for FirebaseDatabase > Frameworks > FirebaseDatabase.framework > Headers. Click and drag the FirebaseDatabase.h file and drop it onto your Geo.m file. This should place a file path in your code. Place this after an `#import` within `< >` brackets.

It should look something like this:

`#import </Users/(filePath)/(projectName)/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks/ FirebaseDatabase.framework/Headers/FIRDatabase.h>`

Not a permanent solution, and could cause problems when sharing the file with collaborators, as the path of the file may change. But it will get GeoG

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following code at this moment:

```
import "../../../FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks/FirebaseDatabase.framework/Headers/FIRDatabase.h"
```